# How to split a byte array by new line characters ("\n" or "\r\n")

Tags: rust

I'm using the `bytes` crate to store a `u8` byte array. I need to split the byte array into individual "lines" of bytes (`Vec<Vec<u8>>`). I could use the `.lines()` method but the problem is not all the data is UTF-8 encoded. I have tried this:

```
let mut chunks = bytes.chunks(2).peekable();
let mut lines = Vec::new();

fn next_line(chunks: &mut std::iter::Peekable<Chunks<u8>>) -> Vec<u8> {
  chunks
    .take_while(|i| *i != [0xD, 0xA])
    .flatten()
    .map(|i| *i)
    .collect::<Vec<u8>>()
}

while let Some(_) = chunks.peek() {
  lines.push(next_line(&mut chunks))
}
```

`[0xD, 0xA]` represents `\r\n` but this only splits CRLF lines and doesn't take into account `\n`.

Comment: I don't know Rust and landed here by mistake, but how about splitting on 0A, then removing any trailing 0D?

Answer (score 1):

I ended up splitting on the `0xA` byte and then trimming the lines of the `0xD` byte.

```
let mut lines = bytes
  .split(|b| b == &0xA)
  .map(|line| line.strip_suffix(&[0xD])
  .unwrap_or(line));
```